# RMySQL error connecting to Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, r

I'm starting learning to use MySQL and, more specifically, I'm trying to learn how to connect and make it interact with Access and R.
I recently create an odbc connecting Access to R. I successfully used R libraries to retrieve it and use sql queries. So I moved to R + Mysql. 
Here starts my problem!
After installing RODBC I installed RMySQL and tried to use "dbConnect". Here follows my code:

```
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("MySQL"), user = "root", password = "mypwd", dbname = "mydbname")
```

where "mypwd" it's the password I inserted when created my MySQL ODBC Unicode Driver and "mydbname" it's the database name I connected. Just for sake of information, I already tested this odbc by transfering tables from Access and Mysql. So my doubts are related only to connection between Mysql and R.

So, let's see my error when running the code line above:

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded
```

I already read other posts about the need to change the Preferred Authentication Plugin.
I found this line code as solution:

```
ALTER USER user
  IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password 
  BY 'password';
```

So....please, tell me if I should change this code line into:

```
ALTER USER root
  IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password 
  BY 'mypwd';
```

Is it correct? Or I completely missed the point.
Sorry for my question but as I said, I'm a completely newbie. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Yes did you try with 'mypwd'? That should fix the issue.

Comment: No I asked my question BEFORE "altering" my Authentication password. In shorts, I haven't written the "Alter user......" code line yet. So u confirm I can open Mysql and write the above line code?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your host address ?

Try the code something like this

```
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("MySQL"), host="192.100.XX.XX",db="df", user="root", password="mypwd")
```

Comment: I'm using "localhost" as it's the way I saved it when created the odbc Mysql driver.

Comment: Then replace host="localhost"

Comment: I was looking at my default password permissions and I found out that, the password I used when created my odbc driver it's not that used as "default" pwd.   I mean, when I created my Mysql odbc driver,  I did it inventing "mypwd" as password. But my localhost has a longer (not revealed) password. So my question is: which password should I write in R for opening the database inside my odbc created? Last question: why in the R code, I don't have to write my odbc name but just "Mysql"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems I found out a workaround for my problem.

Instead of using "dbConnect" I used "odbcConnect". Here follows my working code:

```
channel <- odbcConnect("Myodbcname", uid="root")
df <- sqlQuery(channel, "SELECT * from mytable", as.is = TRUE)
```

"Myodbcname" is the name I saved for my DSN Name and DSN System.
So, now I can use my sql queries on my table and work on it.

At this point I need to understand the difference between the function "odbcConnect" and "dbConnect". Because if I don't need the latter I can ignore for the moment.       Maybe I have to open a new thread with a link to this one.                            Not sure what Stackoverflow prefers me to do.